# How to build 2D array when looping through sets of data using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, the data looks like this:

[image]

The code below build an array like this:

```
[1,"Forro","Teste Molde",2,"36 + 38 + 40 + 42",4,8,"Não Espelhado","Tecido/Pé","Obs",2,"Tag Código Produto","Molde 2",5,"36 + 40",2,10,"Sim","Tecido/Pé2","Obs 2"]
```

But it needs to be like this, starting in `Risco` and ending in `Obs`:

```
[
 [1,"Forno","Teste Molde",2,"36 + 38 + 40 + 42",4,8,"Não Espelhado","Tecido/Pé","Obs"],
 [2,"Tag Código Produto","Molde 2",5,"36 + 40",2,10,"Sim","Tecido/Pé2","Obs 2"]
]
```

Here's the code I'm wrestling with:

```
function salvarCorte(status) {
  if (status != '') {
    const dadosCorte = sheetCorte.getRange(1, 1, sheetCorte.getLastRow(), sheetCorte.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    let outerArray= [];
    var innerArray = [];
    const parametrosRisco = ["Risco", "Matéria Prima", "Molde", "Tamanho", "Grade", "Consumo Unit.", "Espelhado", "Tecido/Pé", "Obs", "Qtd/Peças"];
    let startedArray = false
    for (let r = 0; r < dadosCorte.length; r++) {
      if (dadosCorte[r][0] == 'Risco') {
        startedArray = true
      }
      if (startedArray == true) {
        if (parametrosRisco.indexOf(dadosCorte[r][0]) > -1) {
          innerArray .push(dadosCorte[r][1]);
        }
        if (parametrosRisco.indexOf(dadosCorte[r][2]) > -1) {
          innerArray .push(dadosCorte[r][3]);
        }
        if (dadosCorte[r][0] == 'Obs') {
          startedArray = false;
        }
      }
    }
    outerArray.concat(innerArray )
  }
}
```

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I saw your script, from `outerArray.concat(innerArray )`, I thought that your current value couldn't be replicated. So, I'm worried that your showing script might be different from the script for replicating your showing 1st value.

So, in your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
var sheetCorte = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet"); // Please set the sheet name.
const dadosCorte = sheetCorte.getRange(1, 1, sheetCorte.getLastRow(), sheetCorte.getLastColumn()).getValues();
const parametrosRisco = ["Risco", "Matéria Prima", "Molde", "Tamanho", "Grade", "Qtd/Peças", "Consumo Unit.", "Espelhado", "Tecido/Pé", "Obs"];
const obj = dadosCorte.reduce((o, [a, b, c, d]) => {
  if (a && parametrosRisco.includes(a)) o[a] = o[a] ? [...o[a], b] : [b];
  if (c && parametrosRisco.includes(c)) o[c] = o[c] ? [...o[c], d] : [d];
  return o;
}, {});
const v = parametrosRisco.map(e => obj[e]);
const res = v[0].map((_, c) => v.map(r => r[c]));
console.log(res)
```

- In this sample, first, an object is created using `parametrosRisco`. And, using `parametrosRisco`, your expected values are retrieved from the object.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: This an interesting way to do a push `[...o[c], d]`

Answer (score 0):

#### Building 2D Array Row by Row

```
function myfunk() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet0"); // Please set the sheet name.
  const vs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const headers = ["Section", "Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5", "Name6", "Name7", "Name8", "Name9"];
  const obj = vs.reduce((o, [a, b, c, d], i) => {
    if (a && headers.includes(a)) {
      o.row.push(b);
      if(o.row.length == headers.length) {
        o.r.push(o.row);
        o.row = [];
      }
    }
    if (c && headers.includes(c)) {
      o.row.push(d);
    }
    return o;
  }, { row: [],r: [] });
  console.log(obj.r);
}

Execution log
11:30:09 PM Notice  Execution started
11:30:10 PM Info    [ [ 1,
    'Value11',
    'Value2',
    'Value3',
    'Value4',
    'Value5',
    'Value6',
    'Value7',
    'Value8',
    'Value19' ],
  [ 2,
    'Value21',
    'Value2',
    'Value3',
    'Value4',
    'Value5',
    'Value6',
    'Value7',
    'Value8',
    'Value29' ],
  [ 3,
    'Value31',
    'Value2',
    'Value3',
    'Value4',
    'Value5',
    'Value6',
    'Value7',
    'Value8',
    'Value39' ] ]
11:30:11 PM Notice  Execution completed
```

My Sheet:

| Section | 1 |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | Value11 |  |  |
| Name2 | Value2 |  |  |
| Name3 | Value3 |  |  |
| Name4 | Value4 | Name5 | Value5 |
| Name6 | Value6 |  |  |
| Name7 | Value7 |  |  |
| Name8 | Value8 |  |  |
| Name9 | Value19 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
| Section | 2 |  |  |
| Name1 | Value21 |  |  |
| Name2 | Value2 |  |  |
| Name3 | Value3 |  |  |
| Name4 | Value4 | Name5 | Value5 |
| Name6 | Value6 |  |  |
| Name7 | Value7 |  |  |
| Name8 | Value8 |  |  |
| Name9 | Value29 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
| Section | 3 |  |  |
| Name1 | Value31 |  |  |
| Name2 | Value2 |  |  |
| Name3 | Value3 |  |  |
| Name4 | Value4 | Name5 | Value5 |
| Name6 | Value6 |  |  |
| Name7 | Value7 |  |  |
| Name8 | Value8 |  |  |
| Name9 | Value39 |  |  |